# How to extract the data from a Highcharts trend plot on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, python, html, highcharts, web-crawler

I'm not familiar with front end techniques.So I'm not sure if this can actually works. Here is a web page about the residential vacancy rate of a suburb 2000: https://sqmresearch.com.au/graph_vacancy.php?postcode=2000.

Now that I have the HTML that renders the trend plot, can we get the data behind it, for example, the vacancy rate in the most recent month? In this plot, the last month (March 2023)'s vacancy rate is 3.1% and the vacancy number is 292. **These numbers are shown only when hovering the cursor on that month in the plot.**

It shows "Highcharts" in bottom right. Can we get the data using Python or JavaScript?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to [all chart options](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart) by the global variable `Highcharts`.

Call the below JS code:

- to access pure data: `Highcharts.charts[0].userOptions.series[1].data`
- to access data: `Highcharts.charts[0].series[1].points`

Comment: Thanks! It is the data I need. BTW, is it possible to get the x-axis values as well? (from Jan 2005, Feb 2005, ... to Mar 2023)

Comment: Hi @CyberPlayerOne, Yes, sure. You need to only convert `x` values from timestamps in milliseconds to dates. For example `new Date(Highcharts.charts[0].series[1].points[0].x)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to retrieve the data from a rendered Highcharts graph with Javascript (Python would be a little harder I suppose). Go to the website, open your development console (F12 on most Chromium browers), open the console tab and execute this: `$('#hichartcontainerVR').highcharts().series`. It outputs two series, one for the bars and one for the line. Each of them has a data property which represents all data points (last entry = last month). The `x` value is probably the value you're looking for.